# filtering the date and time column with the latest date and time provided

Tags: r

I have multiple columns of date in my dataframe now I want to `filter` the database with latest date and time , so I want to `filter` data before the provided date and time.

getting error below

Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(c1 =c("1/12/2023 1:26", "1/16/2023 1:26", "1/11/2023 1:40", "1/18/2023 2:05", 
                       "1/24/2023 2:05", "1/25/2023 2:10"),
                 c1=c("AK","AN","DD","MA","DE","NY"))


df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(c1, mdy_hm)) 
df2 <- df2 %>% filter(c1 >= "1/24/2023 2:05")
```

Comment: Note you have a typo in your last date entry ("1/125/2023 2:10"), you cannot have 125 day clearly. Also, why use `as.Date` when you use `mdy_hm` in your first `mutate`? Fixing the typo and changing `as.Date` to `mdy_hm` should fix your cod. (Also not sure why you name both columns to `c1`)

Comment: tried but still facing the same error

Comment: No, you did not replace `as.Date` with `mdy_hm`

Answer (score 0):

Since `c1` is converted to `dttm` format, you need to convert your filtering parameter to match that.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    c1 = c(
      "1/12/2023 1:26",
      "1/16/2023 1:26",
      "1/11/2023 1:40",
      "1/18/2023 2:05",
      "1/24/2023 2:05",
      "1/25/2023 2:10"
    ),
    c1 = c("AK", "AN", "DD", "MA", "DE", "NY")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(c1, mdy_hm)) %>% 
  as_tibble()


df %>% 
  filter(c1 >= mdy_hm("1/24/2023 2:05")) # Added mdy_hm()

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  c1                  c1.1 
  <dttm>              <chr>
1 2023-01-24 02:05:00 DE   
2 2023-01-25 02:10:00 NY
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we filter with the index of the needed value:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(date)) %>% 
  filter(date >= date[which(df$date == "1/24/2023 2:05")])

   date name
1 2023-01-24 02:05:00   DE
2 2023-01-25 02:10:00   NY
```